# about used value on Progress Bar

Tags: android, multithreading, progress-bar

I am developing game in android. I want to used to value progress of Progress Bar to do force shot a arrows .And this is my code :

```
public class TheArrows extends Activity {
    ProgressBar myProgressBar;
    private int myProgress=0;
    private int t=0;

    @Override public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        myProgressBar=(ProgressBar)findViewById(R.id.progressbar_Horizontal);
        app.quabongchuyendong.QuaBongView quaBongView=(app.quabongchuyendong.QuaBongView) findViewById(R.id.qua_bong);
        quaBongView.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {
            @Override public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent event) {
                if(event.getAction()==MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN){ t=1; }
                if(event.getAction()==MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE){ t=1; }
                if(event.getAction()==MotionEvent.ACTION_UP){ t=0; }
                return false;
            }
        });
        new Thread(myThread).start();
    }

    private Runnable myThread = new Runnable(){
        @Override public void run() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub 
            while (myProgress<100){
                try{
                    myHandle.sendMessage(myHandle.obtainMessage());
                    Thread.sleep(100);
                } catch(Throwable t){ }
            }
        }

       Handler myHandle = new Handler(){
            @Override public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
                if(t==1) myProgress++;
                myProgressBar.setProgress(myProgress);
            } 
        };
    };

    public int progressValue(){
        return myProgress;
    }
}
```

Although I have `myProgress++;` why `myProgress` in `progressValue()` doesn't change? Please help me.

Comment: Are you sure you get `t == 1` in the cases you expect you do?

Comment: I use t==1,when action_down and action_move force of arrow will increase,so when action_up it won't.What's your idea?

Comment: The events of down and up might be happening in such a sequence, that `t` is always zero (up is setting `t` to zero). I am not quite certain of the goal, but if you want the counter to increase on each move and down, why don't you increase the `myProgress` variable in the `onTouch` function?

Comment: I try.but myProgress in public int progressValue() don't change.

Answer (score 0):

new Thread(myThread).start();
Should be in OnTouch befaore return statement;

Comment: Your mind is :public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent event) {
    new Thread(myThread).start();
    if(event.getAction()==MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN){
     t=1;
    }
    if(event.getAction()==MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE){
     t=1;
    }
    if(event.getAction()==MotionEvent.ACTION_UP){
     t=0;
    }
    return false;

Comment: it still doesn't change .I don't understand

Answer (score 0):

Try This :

```
 @Override public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent event) {
                if(event.getAction()==MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN){ t=1; }
                else if(event.getAction()==MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE){ t=1; }
                else if(event.getAction()==MotionEvent.ACTION_UP){ t=0; }  
     new Thread(myThread).start(); 
                return false;
            }
        });
```

and Remove if(t==1) condition in handler   Handler

```
   myHandle = new Handler(){
    @Override public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
        myProgress++;
        myProgressBar.setProgress(myProgress);
    } 
};
```

};

Comment: I use t==1,when action_down and action_move force of arrow will increase,so when action_up it won't.So I can catch value progressbar at this time to do force for arrow